# ReactNavigation: Problem with calling navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an error with my code

```
export default function SignIn({ navigation }) {
  const [destination, setDestiantion] = useState("");
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={value => {
          typedText(value);
          setDestiantion(value === "Employee" ? "SignUp1" : "SignUp2");
        }}
        value={text}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate({ destination })} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

But my simulator said:

> while calling navigate with an object as the argument you need to specify name or key.

Someone help me please, thank you very much.

Comment: Pretty sure you should call `navigation.navigate(destination);` - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#navigate

Answer (score 1):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate({destination})}/>
```

**Replace with**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("destination")}/>
```

Comment: I just fix by
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(destination)}/>

Answer (score 0):

Insted of this :
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate({destination})}/>`

use it like this :
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(destination)}/>`

a destination with out the { } braces

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate({ destination })} />
```

Try this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate( destination )} />
```